# Android Browser link sharing doesn't always update URL

Tags: android, android-intent

For the code below, I'm having a problem sharing a link from Chrome browser to my app.

What works: In Chrome, I click on the three dots and select share. I then get a bunch of app icons and I click mine. The URL arrives correctly in my app.

What doesn't work: In Chrome, I click on the three dots again. Since I just shared with my app, my app's icon shows up on the right next to share. When I click it, the app reports the URL from before, not the current URL.

At any time, if I do it the long way, the URL is correct. By long way, I mean, select share and the click my app from the list of shareable icons.

What do I need to change to get the correct link from Chrome via both sharing paths?

My code can be found here: https://github.com/mmccoo/BrowserShare

Here are the interesting files (this is a fresh empty AndroidStudio project and I only changed the three files below):

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.mmccoo.browsershare;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "com.mmccoo.mytestmay2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintext);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();

            String str = "";
            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                str += (key + ":" + bundle.get(key));
            }
            textView.setText(str);
            Log.d(TAG, "bundle: " + str);
        }

        if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_SEND) {
            String newweburl = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Log.d(TAG, "got url " + newweburl);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "other intent");
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mmccoo.browsershare">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mmccoo.browsershare.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/maintext"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the second intent comes through `onNewIntent`?

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev that doesn't change anything. I was hopeful.

Comment: If your activity is already running, the intent from `getIntent()` is not replaced by the new one. It is only passed into [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) method.